# More aggressive TCP/IP?

Tags: networking

Is it possible for a more "aggressive" TCP strategy to effectively prioritize a user's traffic on a network?

It seems that increasing the window size, or decreasing the packet resend times, or similar measures could allow a single user to make more effective use of a network (to the expense of other users, obviously.)

Is this correct/possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network packets don't have a "user" field, so the most you can do is identify packets from a user on the host where those packets originate, and priorize them on this host. This won't change anything about how those packets are treated in the rest of the network.

Alternatively, if you control the network (or part of the network), you can use the above identification to mark the packet in some other way, and then priorize those marked packets in the (part of the) network you control.

Have a look at traffic control (`tc`) and packet rewriting (`iptables`).

Modifying TCP behaviour based on the user (for example, by putting the user in a network namespace, and modifying the TCP settings in this namespace) probably won't work: If the network is already congested, packets get dropped and full buffers cause latency everywhere, sending packets more aggressively will just make everything worse for everyone.

But you are free to experiment in your local network, of course.

And if the practical application you had in mind is not quality of service in your own local network, but something along the lines of "I'm sharing a flat with some other guys, and I am very selfish and want to watch Youtube videos without waiting, while it's ok if the other guys wait": This won't work at all. You are not providing useful content for someone else, which you could priorize, you are downloading content, and the bottleneck is on the ISP side of the DSL (or whatever) line between the ISP and your flat. And the ISP controls this side and decides how to priorize packets, so nothing you do will change anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

TCP parameters such as 'windows size' and 'packet resend time' are usually adjusted automatically by TCP implementation code. In general it is quite efficient. However at some special cases such as network bandwidth overload or huge latency or frequently fluctuating network load one user manually tweaking those parameters can gain some benefit over other users.